# Alter Table in SQL Server 2008:=> Gives me error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have created `CustomerTbl` in SQL Server 2008.

For that i have,

Right Clicking the Table Folder in `ServerExplorer` and selecting `Add New Table`.

**1.** Now i Have Added three column say `CustomerID`, `FirstName`, `LastName` with datatype `int`,`varchar(50)`,`varchar(50)` respectively.

**2.** Now save the table with `CustomerTbl` name.

**3.** now I reopen the Table Defination by RightClicking Table inside `ServerExporer` and Selecting `OpenTableDefination`.

**4.** Now i changing the Property of `CustomerID` column.
I need to automatically increment the value by One each time new record inserted in table.
for that I set IsIdentity property to true.
 using selecting field and ColumnPropery Tab.

**5.** But Problem Occur when i try to save the table. I am getting following error box.

**why i can't make any changes in table's fields property after we have created table and saved it once.???**

Please help....

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a setting in SQL Server Managment Studio.

Menu Tools - Options - Designers - Prevent saving changes that require table re-creation

Comment: Thanks for answering...but i don't have installed `SQL Server Managment Studio` i just creating database from `ServerExplorer`.     is there any tool or option for that?

Comment: @Aryan Sorry, don't know about ServerExplorer. The error is the same as in SSMS so I would guess you have a similar setting for ServerExplorer in there somewhere.

Comment: `ServerExplorer` comes in any version of `Visual Studio`. for seeing the `ServerExplorer` window go=> view==>select `ServerExplorer`

Comment: @Aryan Yes I know that. Just don't use it :).

Comment: Ok ..but is there any way to see the script of table we have created in SqlServer?????

Comment: @Aryan  I suggest you install SSMS http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=7593 and take it from there. You can use that to alter your tables and to create scripts if you like.

Comment: @Aryan SuryaWansi: I believe the Server Explorer (inside Visual Studio, right?) uses the same settings as the SSMS does - try to disable that setting, then it *should* work in VS Server Explorer, too, I believe